# Managing a different python version as a branch in git

Tags: python, git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I am working on a python app that uses python 2.4, postgres 8.2 and old versions of pygresql, xlrd, etc. Because of this it is quite a pain to use, and has to be used in a windows xp VM. There are other problems such as the version of xlrd doesn't support .xlsx files, but the new version of xlrd doesn't work with python 2.4, understandably.

I recently made a branch called 'upgrade' where I started to try to get it working with up to date versions of the libraries (python 2.7), for instance unicode handling has changed a bit so required some changes here and there.

Most of the work I'm doing on the app should work in both environments, but it's nicer to work on the upgrade branch because it doesn't need to run in a vm.

So my question is how can I make commits using the upgrade branch but then apply them to the master branch so they will still apply to the old version of the software the client is using? I realise I can cherry pick commits off the upgrade branch onto master but it seems a bit wrong, having commits in both branches. I'm thinking maybe I should be rebasing the upgrade branch so it is always branching off head after the most recent commits, but then that would mean committing to the master branch which means working in a VM.

Hope this makes some kind of sense, I'll try and do some diagrams if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you should probably commit in your master branch, then rebase your upgrade branch, it will make more sense in your repository history.

If those commits are working on both environments, you should use a different branch based on the master one, so you can work out on the newer version of python, then merge it in the master, then rebase your upgrade branch.